# Printing the next line after a word matches between two TXT files

Tags: python

I was able to find a stack-overflow code that already existed on creating a list and comparing to a txt file which has been great. However I want to print the next line in the txt file as well once the word matches I tried using `(next (f), end "")` and `print(''.join(islice(f, 3)))` but I am unable to get the results I want.

Below is the code. Again I am taking no credit for the code, it is from this original stack overflow post [How to search a text file for a specific word in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27269429/how-to-search-a-text-file-for-a-specific-word-in-python)

```
import os

os.chdir(r"xx")

def createlist():
    items = []
    with open('phrases.txt') as input:
        for line in input:
            items.extend(line.strip().split(','))
    return items

print(createlist())
word_list = createlist()

with open('text.txt') as f
    for word in (sum([x.split() for x in f.read().split('\n')], [])):
        if word in word_list:
            print (word)
        else:
            StopIteration
```

Comment: As an aside, hardcoding `os.chdir()` inside your script reduces its usefulness. Simply have it search two files in the current directory, or accept two file names as command-line parameters so you can run it on any two files in any two directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.strip().split():
            if word in word_list:
                print (word)
                print (next(f))
            else:
                StopIteration
```

To display next line from a file opened as `msg`, use `next(msg)` within a `for line in msg:` loop.